# How do I read project dependencies from pyproject.toml from my setup.py, to avoid duplicating the information in both files?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, beeware, pyproject.toml

We're upgrading to use [*BeeWare's Briefcase*](https://beeware.org/project/projects/tools/briefcase/) [*0.3.1*](https://pypi.org/project/briefcase/0.3.1/) for packaging, which uses `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py` to specify how to package, including which dependencies to include in a package.

Here's a minimal example of a `pyproject.toml` for *briefcase*:

```
[tool.briefcase.app.exampleapp]
formal_name = "exampleapp"
description = "something"
requires = ['PyQt5', 'qtconsole']
sources = ['exampleapp']
```

We'd like to access the list of requires from `setup.py`, so we wouldn't have to replicate it in both files, and keep them in sync. We're not ready to switch away from [*setuptools*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/), this is only for packaging. The alternative is of course to let `setup.py` auto-generate the `pyproject.toml` file, but that seems a little backwards to the intention with [*PEP 518*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

Comment: I don't know much about _briefcase_, but I would assume that no `setup.py` file at all is required. Maybe better chances over there: https://beeware.org/community/getting-help/

Comment: If you want to keep both `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`, I guess you could write a bit of code in `setup.py` that parses the _Toml_ file, but then `setup.py` needs an external dependency on a Toml library (since there is no Toml parser in Python's standard library). Seems like it could be feasible somehow (maybe with some compromise).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer might be outdated. I do not have time to investigate right now. I recommend checking the *briefcase* resources for more up-to-date information. For example this section of the doc might be relevant: https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pep621-compatibility

---

As far as I can tell, *briefcase* isn't actually *PEP 517* compatible (at least not by default). It uses a `pyproject.toml` file, but doesn't fill up the `[build-system]` section, so it should be possible to set an actual *PEP 517* build backend in that file without causing conflict.

`pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = [
    'setuptools',
    'toml',
]

[tool.briefcase.app.exampleapp]
formal_name = 'exampleapp'
description = 'something'
requires = ['PyQt5', 'qtconsole']
sources = ['exampleapp']
```

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pathlib

import pkg_resources
import setuptools
import toml

def _parse_briefcase_toml(pyproject_path, app_name):
    pyproject_text = pyproject_path.read_text()
    pyproject_data = toml.loads(pyproject_text)
    briefcase_data = pyproject_data['tool']['briefcase']
    app_data = briefcase_data['app'][app_name]
    setup_data = {
        'name': pkg_resources.safe_name(app_data['formal_name']),
        'version': briefcase_data['version'],
        'install_requires': app_data['requires'],
        # ...
    }
    return setup_data

def _setup():
    app_name = 'exampleapp'
    pyproject_path = pathlib.Path('pyproject.toml')
    setup_data = _parse_briefcase_toml(pyproject_path, app_name)
    setuptools.setup(**setup_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _setup()
```

Then *pip* and other *PEP 517*-compatible frontends should be able to build and install the project by delegating to *setuptools* while taking care to correctly setup a build environment containing both *setuptools* and *toml*.

I guess it would be also possible to let *briefcase* handle the parsing of the `pyproject.toml` file (maybe with `briefcase.config.parse_config(...)`) but it's not documented so I don't know how stable these APIs are.

Comment: I like `toml.load(pyproject_path.open())` for reading the file